# tema Wordpress 'Minamaze' não ficou responsivo quando ativo

Tags: wordpress, layout-responsivo

Apliquei o tema *Minamaze* do *Wordpress* que foi escolhido por ser responsivo, porém ele não fica quando aplicado. Único plugin que tenho ativo é para um form e-mail (*contact form7*). Versão do *wordpress* está atualizada (`4.8.1`). Ele não altera o *layout* em nenhum dos navegadores testados, nem em celular.

Comment: Posta pelo menos o link do blog, algum código. Não tem como saber sem ter nada pra ver.

Comment: desculpe... segue link:
http://plusagencia.com.br/site/plus

Comment: Você tem algum css personalizado?

Comment: estou evitando mexer nos códigos, sei que isto é complicado se alguma coisa dá errado... a única coisa que eu alterei, foi retirar a assinatura do tema e a marca do wordpress. de resto, está tudo padrão.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Analisando o CSS da página informada no link, não parece realmente estar pronta para o responsivo. Identifiquei no arquivo `style.css` do tema, a linha 149 que tem uma declaração que deixa a largura fixa. Alterando de `min-width` para `max-width` o layout já começa a se comportar como responsivo.

Portanto altere na linha 149 do style.css para:

```
body.layout-fixed,
body.layout-fixed #body-core,
body.layout-fixed #site-header,
body.layout-fixed #notification { 
    min-width: 960px;
}
```

E como a própria classe diz, `.layout-fixed`, é provável que no tema tenha alguma opção que ainda converta e layout para responsivo.

Comment: deu certo Diego! Mudei esta configuração que você disse e já ficou melhor... mas ainda está bem estranho: menu e demais elementos... mas achei que estas configurações fossem automáticas, uma vez que no tema, quando coloco 'visualizar' ele aparece responsivo. Mas vou dar mais uma olhada nas opções e ver se encontro alguma menção de 'trocar' para responsivo como um todo.
Muito obrigada pela ajuda Diego!

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o que estava acontecendo de errado!

Theme Options > General Settings > Enable Fixed Layout
nesta opção, NÃO é apropriado ligar, pois é aqui que o layout deixa de ser responsivo.
Check to enable fixed layout.(i.e. Disable responsive layout)

Passei batido nesta opção das outras vezes... #ficaadica!

Mas obrigada pela ajuda!